# A table by specific columns content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, razor

I have a table that should eventually have 5 columns which I want to be able to sort though only the value of one column, "Name". This is what my function looks like so far:

```
function RenderResultsByName() {
    //Declaration of variables
    var nameInput, nameFilter, ul, li, a, i;

    //Set the variables accorging to matching id's

    //Name
    nameInput = document.getElementById('nameInput');
    nameFilter = nameInput.value.toUpperCase();

    ul = document.getElementById("UL");
    li = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

    console.log(li[0]);

    //Loop trough items and hide those who don't match the query-->
    for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(nameFilter) > -1) {
            li[i].style.display = "";
        }
        else {
            li[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

The HTML looks like this

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-3">
    <label>Namn: </label><br />
    <input type="text" id="nameInput" onkeyup="RenderResultsByName()" placeholder="Sök efter namn..." /> <br /> <br />
</div>
</div>

<br /><br />

<table id="UL" class="table table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Yada</th>
    <th>Yada</th>
    <th>Yada</th>
    <th>Yada</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@item.visitor.FullName</td>
    </tr>
}
</table>
```

I tried to apply a class "tdOfName" on all the 's in the Name column, but after that the sort stopped working because the a variable became undefined.

How would you solve this?

Comment: Can you add the html code? To be fair, your loop doesn't seems to sort it by name.

Comment: Create an array of the values, and then use array methods to accomplish your task (like filter, and sort).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, two things for your HTML code:

1. First a piece of advice, add `thead` and `tbody` to your tables to simplify jquery row selectors (and is a good practice, anyway).
2. You're creating 5 columns in the head row but only one in the rest. You have to add the rest or set a colspan.

   ```
   <table id="UL" class="table table-bordered">
     <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Yada</th>
         <th>Yada</th>
         <th>Yada</th>
         <th>Yada</th>
       </tr>
     <thead>

     <tbody>
       @foreach (var item in Model) {
         <tr>
           <td>@item.visitor.FullName</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>
         </tr>
       }
     <tbody>
   </table>
   ```

Then, you say sort but your function is trying to show/hide rows attending at the input of the value. I can't see any sign of sorting. In case what you want is show/hide rows that has the input value in the first column, you can simplify it with this...

```
jQuery.expr[':'].icontains = function(a, i, m) {
    return jQuery(a).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(m[3].toUpperCase()) >= 0;
};

$('input#nameInput').on('keyup',function() {
    $('table#UL tbody tr').hide().filter(':has(td:first:icontains('+this.value+'))').show();
});
```

Here you have an fiddle example... https://fiddle.jshell.net/rigobauer/4rzf4wt7/

Is this what you're looking for?

I hope it helps.